# ReadToEnd() does not read white space

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-8, split, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to read all contents from a file using ReadToEnd(). But it does not read white space. 
This is the text which is to be read

> 11/07/2014 h~~`

This has a white space after the date(I have added a white space after date while writing into the file. I rechecked by opening the file in NotePad. The space exists.)

But while reading using ReadToEnd. The string obtained has no space after the date. I use that space to split the date from the rest of the string.

Any clues? If its not possible, any other method to efficiently split a date from the rest of the string.

Comment: What is the encoding in which the file was encoded? and what's the encoding you're using to read the same? Are they both same?

Comment: Also did you checked whether other methods like `Read`, `ReadLine` etc helps? That shouldn't make any difference but worth trying.

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, including the file, and giving precise diagnostics as to what `ReadToEnd` returns. Are you sure the file is all text? Have you examined it within a hex editor?